# Cypress | Chai assertions executes outside if else condition. Assertions are mentioned inside if condition

Tags: if-statement, cypress, chai, assertion

I am writing a cypress custom command, which fetches a json response from an API end point. I am writing some assertions on the json response. However, I have a if-else condition to be executed. See below.

```
cy.getReportJson('84b636f4-c8f0-4aa4-bdeb-15abf811d432',user).then(report=> {
                    
                    if(services.request_criminal_record_check.include){
                        console.log('inside if')
                        cy.wait(30000)
                        expect(report.report_summary.rcmp_result.status).equal(data.expected_result.rcmp_result.status)
                        expect(report.report_summary.rcmp_result.overall_score).equal(data.expected_result.rcmp_result.overall_score)
                        expect(report.report_summary.rcmp_result.result).equal(data.expected_result.rcmp_result.result)
                    }
                })
```

When I run this code in a spec file, the Output I get is as follows.

[image]

As you can see, the assertions are running, before the wait command is triggered.
I want cypress to wait for 30 seconds, so that the back-end runs its magic and generates a report and after 30 seconds, i wanna assert on the report json.
Even the console.log is printed after the assertions are executed.

Is this something related to the async nature of Cypress?

Comment: It is not a good practice to wait for this much amount of time. You should implement something with timeouts so that whenever the desired activity is finished then it moves on to the next command.

Comment: @AlapanDas We have a manually induced delay in the Mocked Response to simulate the timelines of real world report generation. Using timeouts is the right way when you are waiting for DOM elements to do something. However, care to elaborate how we can use timeout to wait for an API response,  to get back with specific values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to queue the assertions. `expect()...` runs immediately, but `cy.wait()` is pausing the queue exection.

```js
cy.wait(30000)
cy.then(() => {                 
  expect(...).equal(...)
  expect(...).equal(...)
  expect(...).equal(...)
})
```

[image: Log]